# NLP Coreference resolution

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am new in NLP domain and was going through this blog:
https://blog.goodaudience.com/learn-natural-language-processing-from-scratch-7893314725ff

[image]

> London is the capital of and largest city in England and the United
>   Kingdom. Standing on the River Thames in the south-east of England, at
>   the head of its 50-mile (80 km) estuary leading to the North Sea,
>   London has been a major settlement for two millennia. It was founded
>   by the Romans.

I have the experience in NER and POS tagging using spacy.
I would like to know that how i will link the **london** with **it** like:

London is the capital .....

It has been a major settlement..

It was founded by the Romans....

I have tried the Dependency parser but not able to produce the same result.
https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy

I am open to use any other library, please suggest the right approach to achieve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem which you are looking to solve is called *Coreference resolution* .

The dependency parser is generally not the right tool to solve it.

Spacy has a dedicated module called [neuralcoref](https://spacy.io/universe/project/neuralcoref).
Have a look at this page too on [coreference resolution with Spacy](https://www.rangakrish.com/index.php/2019/02/03/coreference-resolution-using-spacy/)

An example:

```
import spacy
import neuralcoref

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)
doc = nlp('London is the capital of and largest city in England and the United Kingdom. It was founded by the Romans.')

print(doc._.coref_clusters)
#output: [London: [London, It]]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @DBaker, I would compare the result of corenlp and spacy performance for coreference-resolution. Thanks again.